# Android: Using TabHost with programmatically created View

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create tabs which will show certain views I create through code. Now I can pass a View to TabHost, but only by id.

So I tried to assign some random id, say 1001 to my programmatically created view -

```
TabHost th = getTabHost();
View v=getMyView(); v.setId(1001);
th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Monthly").setContent(v.getId()));
```

I get a Forced Close when I run this with the message that there is no view number 1001.

Is there any other way I can use my own generated views in TabHost, or a tabbed interface?

Comment: the compiler cant find the gettabHost() function, can you tell something more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the version of the overloaded [`setContent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setContent%28android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory%29) method that takes a [TabHost.TabContentFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabContentFactory.html).

```
th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("tab1")
    .setIndicator("Monthly")
    .setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            if (tag.equals("tab1")) {
                return getMyView();
            }
            return null;
        }));
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. How do you get to know something like this? Reading the documentation?

Comment: @KalEl read the [source code of the API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Tabs2.html). It's very useful!